# How to add data to XML file without overwriting previous data (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

This code saves new data, it overwrites old data with new one.

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "Patient";
    dt.Columns.Add("FIO");
    dt.Columns.Add("NumTel");
           
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
 
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.TableName = "Info";
    dt1.Columns.Add("Ticket");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Doc");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Spec");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Data");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Time");
    ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
 
    DataRow row = ds.Tables["Patient"].NewRow();
    row["FIO"] = textBox1.Text;
    row["NumTel"] = textBox2.Text;
            
    ds.Tables["Patient"].Rows.Add(row);
 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow row1 = ds.Tables["Info"].NewRow();
        row1["Ticket"] = r.Cells[0].Value;
        row1["Data"] = r.Cells[1].Value;
        row1["Time"] = r.Cells[2].Value;
        row1["Doc"] = r.Cells[3].Value;
        row1["Spec"] = r.Cells[4].Value;
        ds.Tables["Info"].Rows.Add(row1);
    }
    ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\Vano\Desktop\XMLSaving - Copy\files\Data.xml");
}
```

In XML it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Patient>
    <FIO>Оля Эрцык Канаева</FIO>
    <NumTel>5678311233</NumTel>
  </Patient>
  <Info>
    <Ticket>489155</Ticket>
    <Doc>МЕЛЬНИК ІВАН ІВАНОВИЧ</Doc>
    <Spec>Стоматолог-ортодонт</Spec>
    <Data>01.02.2021</Data>
    <Час>11:00</Час>
  </Info>
  <Info/>
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to make this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Patient>
    <FIO>Оля Эрцык Канаева</FIO>
    <NumTel>5678311233</NumTel>
  </Patient>
  <Info>
    <Ticket>489155</Ticket>
    <Doc>МЕЛЬНИК ІВАН ІВАНОВИЧ</Doc>
    <Spec>Стоматолог-ортодонт</Spec>
    <Data>01.02.2021</Data>
    <Time>11:00</Time>
  </Info>
<Patient>
    <FIO>Иван Ходор Михайлович</FIO>
    <NumTel>3453453453</NumTel>
  </Patient>
  <Info>
    <Ticket>340999</Ticket>
    <Doc>БОЙКО ГАННА ІВАНІВНА</Doc>
    <Spec>Стоматолог-терапевт</Spec>
    <Data>30.01.2021</Data>
    <Time>13:00</Time>
  </Info>
  <Info/>
</NewDataSet>
```

I think need to make this: when I'm creating DataSet I need to create it from existing XML file and then when saving the old data will remain.
But I don't know how to write it.
Can you help me to improve it?
DataSet ds = derictory to xml file, I really don't know how to write it.

Update
I created this. but it connects structure to XML file when one person saves it.If another guy write something, add it and save it it'll overwrite and previous data will disappear.

1. I filled all text boxes and pressed button "add to columns"

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                   
          
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = textBox5.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = textBox3.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = textBox4.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = textBox6.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = textBox7.Text;
                textBox8.Text = "Бот: Ви додали свій запис!";
            
        }
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q58D.png
```

And after that I'm save it:

```
        {
           
                DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                dt.TableName = "Пацієнт";
                dt.Columns.Add("ПІБ");
                dt.Columns.Add("НомТел");

                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1.TableName = "Інформація";
                dt1.Columns.Add("Квиток");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Лікар");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Спеціальність");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Дата");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Час");
                ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

                DataRow row = ds.Tables["Пацієнт"].NewRow();
                row["ПІБ"] = textBox1.Text;
                row["НомТел"] = textBox2.Text;
                ds.Tables["Пацієнт"].Rows.Add(row);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow row1 = ds.Tables["Інформація"].NewRow();
                    row1["Квиток"] = r.Cells[0].Value;
                    row1["Дата"] = r.Cells[1].Value;
                    row1["Час"] = r.Cells[2].Value;
                    row1["Лікар"] = r.Cells[3].Value;
                    row1["Спеціальність"] = r.Cells[4].Value;
                    ds.Tables["Інформація"].Rows.Add(row1);
                }               ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\VanoPC\Desktop\XMLSavingCopy\files\Data.xml"); 
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Пацієнт>
    <ПІБ>bla bal</ПІБ>
    <НомТел>1123213453</НомТел>
  </Пацієнт>
  <Інформація>
    <Квиток>897292</Квиток>
    <Лікар>МЕЛЬНИК ІВАН ІВАНОВИЧ</Лікар>
    <Спеціальність>Стоматолог-терапевт</Спеціальність>
    <Дата>30.01.2021</Дата>
    <Час>11:00</Час>
  </Інформація>
  <Інформація>
    <Квиток>897292</Квиток>
    <Лікар>ШТЕПА ІВАН АНДРІЙОВИЧ</Лікар>
    <Спеціальність>Стоматолог-ортопед</Спеціальність>
    <Дата>30.01.2021</Дата>
    <Час>15:00</Час>
  </Інформація>
  <Інформація />
</NewDataSet>
```

Yes. XML headlines from unknown words but it doesn't change the meaning.
I don't understand how add new data for new people because it overwrites previous who was the first.
If new guy will come and fill the textboxes and save data, it deletes previous data about another guy. I hope this information will be enough. Maybe I should change something in add method?

Comment: I would actually suggest to ditch using an xml file. Just don't. Today you can easily learn and use single-file DBs like SQLite, which at least in my book is _way_ "beginner-friendly" than dealing with XML. That is of course if you are not _forced_ to use XML or XML-handling is the thing you want to learn.

Comment: @Fildor This is the last part of my school assignment and I was told to do this. ))

Comment: Ok, so you're stuck with XML. I just wanted to bring the possibility to your attention.

Comment: So, analog to the WriteXML, there is [ReadXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=net-5.0). Mind that you have to have two paths now: 1. There is no data to base upon. => Create new DataSet from scratch and save. 2. There is a datafile => Load DataSet from file and add to it. Then save result.

Comment: Mind that you would usually separate UI from all that. File I/O is expensive and as your datafile grows, this may "freeze" your UI for quite some time. But one step after the other. Just a "heads up".

Comment: @Fildor then I have to create an empty file but with the XML structure and a second file where information about the user will be written. After that, I send the user data to an empty file with the XML structure - it might work, but it will write the data based on the empty XML structure without information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with AppendChild Method.

Look at this example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//Create a new node.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("price");
elem.InnerText="19.95";

//Add the node to the document.
root.AppendChild(elem);

Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML...");
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

does this help?

Comment: honestly not, customer writes info about himself in textbox.I made a i made a bunch of text boxes for <FIO> <NumTel> and it covered in box <Patient>  and the same with the second part.I have created a function for adding certain data to columns and it can be seen in Forms.When.If I want to save, it creates Colums for XML with data from textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication181
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Patient"];

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Иван Ходор Михайлович", "3453453453"});

            dt = ds.Tables["Info"];

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "340999", "БОЙКО ГАННА ІВАНІВНА","Стоматолог-терапевт", "30.01.2021", "13:00"});

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `">3453453453</NumTel"` - typo?